# How to turn this into a session cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can I turn this into a session cookie?

I know I would start by getting rid of the exipredays, but when I set the expiredays to 0 the message cbox displays everytime your refresh the page and I could see that getting annoying..

```
<p align="center">DISCLAIMER GOES HERE</p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var agreement = GetCookie();

// checks for cookie and displays disclaimer alert if new user
if(agreement=="")
    {
    var decision = confirm("DISCLAIMER: GOES HERE \n\nClick Ok if you agree to the disclaimer or click Cancel to close this window. \n");
            if(decision == true)
                    {
                    // writes a cookie
                    var expiredays = 7;
                    var exdate=new Date()
                    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays)
                    document.cookie="PartnerAgreement"+ "=" +escape("Agree To Disclaimer")+
                    ((expiredays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toGMTString())
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    // redirect
                    window.location = "/_layouts/signout.aspx";

                    // or close the browser window
                    //window.opener='x';
                    //window.close();
                    }
    }

// gets the Cookie if it exists
function GetCookie()
    {
    if (document.cookie.length>0)
            {
            c_name = "PartnerAgreement";
            c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=")
            if (c_start!=-1)
                    {
                    c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1
                    c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start)
                    if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length
                    return agreement = unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end))
                    }
            }
            return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code says:

```
((expiredays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toGMTString())
```

`0` is not `null` (`0` is "immediately"). Set `expiredays` to `null`.